# Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, crashlytics, google-fabric

It is possible to send invite to the application version for test in firebase. Just like I send in the Fabric invite to test by email.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin from Firebase/Fabric here - the team's currently building out App Distribution for Firebase, which will be the method for inviting your testers to test distributions as you do currently with Beta by Crashlytics in Fabric.

Check out the [roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) for more info on Fabric -> Firebase migration and updates to the status of products like App Distribution. You can also sign up to test out the alpha version when that's ready. Hope that helps!